# Tratamiento de excepciones dentro de un bucle

Tags: java

Pretendo leer dos números enteros mientras los dos datos leidos no sean correctos. Es decir, si en cualquiera de los dos datos se introduce algo que no es un entero, que se vuelva a repetir el bucle do-while. A continuación dejo el código:

```
int a = 0, b = 0;

boolean est;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

do {

    try {
        est = false;
        System.out.print("Introduce el primer numero a: ");
        a = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Introduce el segundo numero b: ");
        b = sc.nextInt();

    } catch (InputMismatchException exc) {

        System.out.println("Error, lo introducido no es valido: " + exc.getMessage());
        est = true;
    }

} while(est);
```

El caso es que al introducir algo que no sea un entero, el bucle se repite de forma indefinida. ¿Dónde puede estar el problema?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: prueba a limpiar el buffer en el catch, por lo demás parece bien lo que haces

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. ¿Cómo podría limpiar el buffer en el catch?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

De la documentación de [Scanner.nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--):

> Scans the next token of the input as an int. This method will throw
>   InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a
>   valid int value as described below. **If the translation is successful,
>   the scanner advances past the input that matched**.

nextInt, si no puede procesar el token, lanza una excepción, pero no pasa al siguiente token. Tienes que hacerlo tú en el bloque `catch`, por ejemplo con `sc.next()`, ignorando el resultado de esa llamada.

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar. Ya está solucionado.

Answer (score 4):

Lo que te recomiendo es que hagas lo siguiente:

En lugar de leer el siguiente `Int` mejor lee el siguiente `next` e intenta parsearlo a `Int`:

```
a = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
```

Con esto también intenta capturar el error `NumberFormatException`:

```
catch (final NumberFormatException asd)
```

y puedes poner lo mismo que tienes en la catch anterior si es que gustas o manejarlo de otra manera.

Comment: Es la que yo también recomiendo.

Comment: Genial, gracias por la recomendación. La probaré.